# How to add millions of documents to ChromaDB efficently

Tags: scalability, langchain, embedding, chromadb

I have 2 million articles that are being chunked into roughly 12 million documents using `langchain`. I want to run a search over these documents so I would like to have them into ideally one chroma database. Would the quickest way to insert millions of documents into chroma database be to insert all of them upon database creation or to use `db.add_documents()`. Right now I'm doing it in `db.add_documents()` in chunks of 100,000 but the time to `add_documents` seems to get longer and longer with each call. Should I just try inserting all 12 million chunks when I create it? I have a GPU and a lot storage and it used to take 30 min per 100K but now were at a little past an hour for adding 100k documents with `add_document`.

```
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter



model_path = "./multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1/"
model_kwargs = {"device": "cuda"}
embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="./multi-qa-MiniLM-L6-cos-v1/",  model_kwargs=model_kwargs)

documents_array = documents[0:100000] 

text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size=500,
    chunk_overlap=50,
    length_function=len,
    is_separator_regex=False,
)

docs = text_splitter.create_documents(documents_array)

persist_directory = "chroma_db"

vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(
    documents=docs, embedding=embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory
)

vectordb.persist()
vectordb._collection.count()


docs = text_splitter.create_documents(documents[500000:600000])

def batch_process(documents_arr, batch_size, process_function):
    for i in range(0, len(documents_arr), batch_size):
        batch = documents_arr[i:i + batch_size]
        process_function(batch)

def add_to_chroma_database(batch):
    vectordb.add_documents(documents=batch)

batch_size = 41000

batch_process(docs, batch_size, add_to_chroma_database)
```